# My CSS and images aren't being displayed Django

Tags: python, css, django

I am learning Django and for some reason my CSS and images are not being displayed. I feel as though I am doing something wrong inside my `HTML` file. I think my files are being collected correctly because when I insert `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/python-logo@2x.png` in my browser I see the image.

This is my project tree:

```
mysite
  \articles
       \static
       \articles
           \css
  \static
       \images
       \css
           default.css
       \js 
  \assets
       \admin
       \images
           python-logo@2x.png
       \css
           default.css
  \templates
       base.html
  \settings.py
```

In my `settings.py`

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Here is my base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %} My Base Template {% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/default.css" %}">

</head> 

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="sidebar">
            {% block sidebar %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/articles/all">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="/admin/">Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
            {% endblock %}  
        </div>  
        <div id="content">
            {% block content %}This is the content area{% endblock %}
            <img src="{% static "images/python-logo@2x.png" %}">
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `static "/assets/images/python-logo@2x.png"` to `static "images/python-logo@2x.png"`

Comment: @Leonardo.Z didn't work =/

Comment: @Leonardo.Z i decided to go with those settings for static files as this is just for practice and i didnt run into problem collecting the static files.

Comment: Let's skip the static tag. Could you visit dev_ser_host:port/static/imgages/python-logo@2x.png? If not, what's the error message return by django?

Comment: @Leonardo.Z yes i can visit it and the image is displayed

Comment: What's the src of that image in the html django rendered?

Comment: You could keep your static files in static folder. Why do you need to make another directory?

Comment: @Leonardo.Z Um im not quite sure what youre asking

Comment: @ArchitVerma That is where they will be retrieved by collectstatic. static is for all the other static files that don't pertain to a specific app

Comment: @Leonardo.Z Do you mean where I got the image? It's a file i downloaded online

Comment: @Leonardo.Z i think i know what you mean. The html is called base.html

Comment: @Liondancer I think django is serving static files correctly. But the `static` tag does not return the correct url to those files. I want to know what the `static` tag returns.

Comment: @Leonardo.Z I am not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Close the syntax with **angle brackets**.
Right now it has been closed with **question mark** in head section.

Comment: I didnt see that but it didnt fix the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To start off, link your .less stylesheets with the rel attribute set to "stylesheet/less"

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

Next, download less.js and include it in a  tag in the  element of your page:

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: why do i need a less compiler?

Comment: When you link more than one .less stylesheet each of them is compiled independently. So any variables, mixins or namespaces you define in a stylesheet are not accessible in any other

Comment: I see but I only have one .css file right now. I vaguely remembering I was required to have a less compiler for JS and twitter bootstrap. I dont think I need one right now in this case but I appreciated the help!

Comment: or maybe path issue '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "../assets/css/default.css" %}">'

Comment: I think it is a path issue as well regarding the django portion. However I am not sure how to fix this =/

Comment: Check this out may this will help [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in your Reddit post, you need to add your `/assets` directory to your `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

I'm not sure why you have your `assets` and `static` files in different directories (and you may want to consider combining these assets), but this should be an adequate solution to your current issues.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

**In settings.py**

Replace

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

With this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

**And in template file**

Replace

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

With this in the template.

```
{% load static %}
```

Note: Put the contents of assets folder inside static folder.

Comment: whats the difference between {load static} and {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: Its the same. The main culprit was the STATIC_ROOT that you have set for the application.